# C Preprocessor - whitespace in #define?

Tags: c, preprocessor

I want to transform

```
void func(
```

into

```
void _func(
```

I tried this:

```
#define void\ func( void _func(
```

but I get an error:

```
test.c(1): error C2008: '\': unexpected in macro definition
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Nope, not possible. Can be done with a good text editor.

Comment: Without copy and replace?  Yes, may be able to use string merging `##` to do this, but I get really jumpy when I see stuff like this.

Comment: To follow up, you don't include the "void " in your macro, but just ## an underscore to the beginning of the passed in value.

Comment: You can achieve something similar to what you want by writing a `TRANSFORM_FUNC` macro which is implemented using the `#` operator inside.  So, in your code you'd write something like: `TRANSFORM_FUNC(func)` and the prepocessor could generate the `void _func` for you.  See this amazing answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45376462/1212725

Comment: good luck when you start debugging it :)